# Laravel Jobs not executing when Redis moved from local to AWS

Tags: laravel, redis, laravel-7, predis, amazon-elasticache

I am having issue moving the Redis queue from local 127.0.0.1 to AWS elastic cache. I have replaced the redis host in .env file and restarted the queue on the server.The php artisan queue:restart shows no error message and displays success message

> Broadcasting queue restart signal.

After switching to AWS the jobs are not picked up for execution. When
I switch the queue back to 127.0.0.1 it works fine.

The redis version on the server was 3.2.6 where as the redis version used on the AWS elastic cache is 6.2.6. We are using predis package(1.1.1).The configurations are given below.

```
'redis' => [
    'cluster' => false,
    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 3),
    ],

    'test_queue' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => env('REDIS_DB', 3),
    ],

],
```

Is there any compatibility issue because of the versions?

Comment: You could try the credentials with redis-cli to see if there is any issue with it, ex: `redis-cli -h host -a pass -p 6390 PING`. And also you could try to clear the cache

Comment: When you say "local" you mean local to the server but not local to your machine? Also check if the cache and the AWS instance are on the same VPC or can be accessed via VPC because the AWS hosted caches are internal VPC only.

Comment: @Lk77 I have cleared the cache and also tried to ping the redis host and it is replying pong in response.

Comment: @apokryfos I have updated the description I meant 127.0.0.1 as local. The redis server is accessible to the server. if it is not accessible it gives error on this command php artisan queue:restart  as connection refused.

Comment: Jobs will not be transferred to the new redis server, are you inserting new jobs or trying to get old jobs to execute ?

Comment: @Lk77 I am inserting new jobs but they are not executed

Comment: Maybe a basic question but are you caching configuration and if so did you do `php artisan config:cache` to recache it after you changed .env file?

Comment: @Lk77 already tried clearing cache etc. The commands don't get executed when moved to AWS redis